# Bootstrap 'offset' created for lower screen resolutions is being displayed on larger screen as well

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

A HTML file, created using Twitter Bootstrap - 3, with a header containing 4 columns. Here's the URL -

http://jsfiddle.net/anujbhai/nuHX6/.

Problem is, inside

```
#module_signup_header
```

even in big-screen where

```
.col-md-offset-1
```

should be working, instead

```
.col-sm-offset-1
```

is taking over the layout, which i think should only be viewed in screens less than 750px width.

..someone please help!! the 'offset' created for lower screen resolutions is being displayed on larger screen,

Answer (score 0):

Below 768px, `col-xs-width` works not col-sm-width.
For more than 768px but less than 992px, col-sm-width works.
For more than 992px but less than 1200, col-md-works.
For more than 1200 px, col-lg works.

For 750px, col-xs should work but since it is not there, next col-sm is in work.

Comment: So what do you suggest? I tried writing down a new class 
    .col-xs-offset-1
but it messes up the layout further more

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually experiencing a similar problem where an offset at the sm size carries over to the md size, even though I'm using their suggested md-offset-0 option. Maybe a push is not considered an offset?

But for your example I would add offset-0, giving you this

```
<div class="col-sm-x col-sm-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 col-md-offset-0">
```

Comment: thanks for hearing me out but ... couldn't follow your concept. It would be greatly helpful if you could look into my fiddle (URL given above), edit it and share. Please!